# Python create and sort list based on variable value

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I was wondering if someone can guide me in the right direction here. I'm working on something but I am stuck on creating and sorting a list based on their value. For example below

```
Sam = 10
John = 20
David = 5
Anthony = 7
Michael = 6

test[Sam, John, David, Anthony, Michael]
print(test)
```

So basically I want to be able to print the values assigned to the variable and then rank them from lowest to highest,
for example; 5, 6, 7, 10, 20

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just letting you know that there are no strings in your provided code. Those are just variable names.

Comment: My apologies, didn't realize it. I have edited the post, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `sorted`

```
Sam = 10
John = 20
David = 5
Anthony = 7
Michael = 6

test = [Sam, John, David, Anthony, Michael]
print(sorted(test))

# [5, 6, 7, 10, 20]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was all I needed.

Comment: Also, is there a way to print the list "test" to display the variables based on their value from low to high? For example test = [David, Michael, Anthony, Sam, John]

Comment: I would suggest using a `dictionary` for that where you can assign for example `{'Sam': 10, 'John': 20 ...}`. In python its not considered "pythonic" to be printing the variables. You can read more about dictionaries [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-python-dictionaries-by-key-or-value/)